# Bluetooth Chat android connection/discovery bug

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing android Bluetooth game, based on BluetoothChat example.
It seems work well, but every 5 - 10 attempt to connect app crashes.It seems, that some buffer is overflowed.I use one device as a server, and another as client. Client (HTC EVO 4G) crashes with this trace :

```
02-04 21:11:54.139: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2048): start
02-04 21:11:54.139: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2048): setState() 0 -> 1
02-04 21:11:54.169: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): new handle 9
02-04 21:11:54.179: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2048): Socket Type: InsecureBEGIN mAcceptThreadThread[Thread-47,5,main]
02-04 21:11:55.870: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(130): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
02-04 21:11:55.890: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2048): connect to: 10:BF:48:E8:C1:26
02-04 21:11:55.890: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2048): setState() 1 -> 2
02-04 21:11:55.900: INFO/BluetoothService(2048): BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:Insecure
02-04 21:11:55.900: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(130): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
02-04 21:11:57.222: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(10:BF:48:E8:C1:26)
02-04 21:11:57.222: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): uuid(system): 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb -1
02-04 21:11:57.232: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): uuid(application): fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66 3
02-04 21:11:57.232: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Making callback for fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66 with result 3
02-04 21:12:05.910: ERROR/BluetoothService.cpp(130): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
02-04 21:12:06.491: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2048): stop
02-04 21:12:35.779: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.779: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 8 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.789: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.789: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 2 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.789: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.789: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 1 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.799: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.799: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.799: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.799: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 7 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.809: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.809: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 4 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.819: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.819: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 6 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.819: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.819: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.819: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 5 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.829: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.829: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.829: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 3 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.829: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.829: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Removing service record 9 for pid 2048
02-04 21:12:35.839: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.839: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.839: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
02-04 21:12:35.839: DEBUG/BluetoothService(130): Tracked app 2048 died
```

And the worst thing, that I cant start connection again - till I reboot my phone.It throws:

```
02-04 21:15:11.381: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2322): start
02-04 21:15:11.381: DEBUG/BluetoothService(2322): setState() 0 -> 1
02-04 21:15:12.432: ERROR/BluetoothService(2322): Socket Type: Insecurelisten() failed
        java.io.IOException: Bad file number
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.throwErrnoNative(Native Method)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.createNewRfcommSocketAndRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:884)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:820)
        at com.insomniacpro.pillows.Bluetooth.BluetoothService$AcceptThread.<init>(BluetoothService.java:312)
        at com.insomniacpro.pillows.Bluetooth.BluetoothService.start(BluetoothService.java:132)
        at com.insomniacpro.pillows.engine.MultiGameActivity.onResume(MultiGameActivity.java:159)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1242)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3904)
```

Sometimes server device (Nexus 7) crashes - and again I must reboot it to start working.
Stack:

```
  java.io.IOException: Error: -1
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.createNewRfcommSocketAndRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:1035)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:951)
    at com.insomniacpro.pillows.Bluetooth.BluetoothService$AcceptThread.<init>(BluetoothService.java:312)
    at com.insomniacpro.pillows.Bluetooth.BluetoothService.start(BluetoothService.java:132)
    at com.insomniacpro.pillows.engine.MultiGameActivity.onResume(MultiGameActivity.java:159)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)

Maybe BluetoothChat app doesnt closes sockets well, when connection is closed?
```

Any help will be usefull!!

Answer (score 0):

At last I ended with such bad solution : calling onFinish() each time when connection is lost or failed. It's appropriate for my case, but not in other. It seems to me, that connectionLost() function in BluetoothChat is incomplete. It should clear ports in another way.

Comment: Even I face this situation.What do you do in the onFinish()? could you pls share